# Changing cat food necessary if no better results in coat?

Tags: cats, diet, skin-condition

I have 1 year old cat with poor coat, I visited a vet several times but he says there is nothing wrong with the cat. His recommendation was to change the cat food.

When I fed my cat "Royal Canin Persian Kitten" his coat was average. Then the vet asked me to switch from "Royal Canin" to "Josera Cat Food". I didn't see any improvement in his coat. Now the vet wants me to switch to "Royal Canin Skin and Care Nutrition" which is really expensive.

1. Should I switch food again?
2. Is a poor coat the result of feeding only dry food, and wet food once or twice a month?
3. What should I feed my cat to improve his coat?

Answer (score 3):

I have no better health advice than your vet has.

But, if my cat was healthy otherwise, I would not change cat food for a really expensive food.

Now, depending on where you live the quality of the cat food might not be up to what is needed. The European Union has rules on that and so even low price dry cat food that claims to be a total / complete food will be healthy for a cat. Try to find out what the rules are in your country. And there might even be some comparative tests on the available cat food.

You might try a small bag of the expensive cat food, see if you find it worth your money.

Comment: I would have visited the vet if I trusted vets of my city, I have already told in question what they advice me. They are only here to make money and my current vet is currently the most educated vet in my city. That is why I ask questions here

Answer (score 2):

While I can only offer primarily anecdote-based information, I have consistently found drastic improvements with my cats' coats when feeding a quality all-wet diet. I will admit up front that I have not tried lower priced wet options, and that an all-wet diet can be more expensive than many kibble-based diets, as well as less convenient. However, four of four cats I've fed this way have very high-quality, soft coats when fed a species-appropriate canned food.

As available foods vary between countries, and recipes may also vary from region to region, the best advice is to do your own research on what ingredients are in foods available for you. A species-appropriate food will be primarily named meat ingredients (avoid "meat" and "meat by-product" ingredients, as there's no telling what they may be), with some added supplemental vitamins, minerals, and vegetables (to simulate the stomach contents of prey). As cats tend to get most of their water through prey, a wet diet will lead to a better hydrated cat, and a cat who is hydrated and receiving proper nutrition will be more likely to have a healthy coat as well.

Answer (score 2):

If your cat is doing healthy in the cat food you have chosen for her, please don't change food again and again.

For Coat, I can give you advice.

1. Try not to bath your cat on a regular basis.
2. Wait for a week or two for proper results.
3. Add Fatty acids (Fish and Salmon) in your cat's food. (With vet advice)

Thanks

Answer (score -4):

Do not change food, if it works well for your cat's age, weight, and breed and is vet recommended. Keep the new food if everything else is fine and healthy. Cats usually don’t like change in their food.

There are supplements like collagen that you can add to your cat's food that may help her coat and be more cost-effective than switching to an expensive food brand. Any brand works as long as it contains *marine collagen peptides* as the active ingredient. And make sure you get a product for cats.
It's typically powder made to sprinkle over food, though this could vary.

I bought some for my 15yo arthritic Maine Coon and saw an improvement in her fur and joints immediately.

Comment: please stop the promotion of (your products?)i have flagged this as spam.

Comment: @trondhansen i am not affiliated with any of "my products." if I was I would hve declared it outright?

Comment: @trondhansen why was this flagged as spam if you don't mind me asking? I didn't say "go buy totallyWags" I just said that worked for me but any brand will do. that isn't promotion thats sharing a story. I didn't even link it, nor diclose the brand

Comment: The way you are writing your answers very strongly resembles a heavy-handed attempt at "organic marketing." You include one or two specific brand names, price points, and a list of selling points. ("Dairy and gluten-free for cats with dietary limits." "Also available for dogs!" and so on.) It's fine to mention brands, but writing/duplicating ad copy for those brands makes it look like you have something to gain, whether that be commission from the link, or payment as an influencer.

Comment: @AllisonC I can see how that may come across as so but I truly have no affiliation with any brands, as I am 18. I just like to make sure people have some recommendations (although they certainly don't have to use them) a place to shop for them, and a price point. I also didn't copy and ads but looking back I can totally see how it looks like I did.  Thank you for your feedback and I greatly appreciate the insight and will use it when formulating other answers.

Comment: Ava, you do realize that this is an _international_ site? For example, of the people interacting with you in comments under your posts, the minority is in the US. That is one of the reasons why product recommendations, even if well meaning, are not a good idea. Neither product nor source nor price point make sense in other locations. (Plus the spam / plugging bit mentioned before.)

Comment: @Stephie AllisonC told me recommendations were just fine. I simply shared ideas (ex. CBD treats) you can buy those anywhere, I just simply shared the brands I used.

Comment: @ava I did no such thing. I said it's okay to mention a brand name, not to throw recommendations around like you're selling them. Please do not put words in my mouth. My comment telling you what is and is not okay is still clearly visible.

Comment: @AllisonC and my answer saying "any brand will be just fine as long at includes..." is still clearly visible. apologies for the miscommunication